# Comparing sub ranges of a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, range

I want to compare a sub range of a char array to another string using strcmp.
I made the dna char array by reading from a textfile and then concatenating them into a longer  char array.

```
char dna[10] = "ATGGATGATGA";
char STOP_CODON[3] = "TAA"; 
int TS1 = strcmp(&STOP_CODON[0]),dna[0]);
int TS2 = strcmp(&STOP_CODON[1]),dna[1]); 
int TS3 = strcmp(&STOP_CODON[2]),dna[2]);

if(T1+T2+T3) == 3 {
   int T = 1;  
}
```

So if they all match then T returns as true(1)
   I want to compare the STOP_CODON with dna in subranges of three chars.
   I cant figure a way to do this simply. In matlab you can do:

```
strcmp(STOP_CODON[1:3],dna[1:3])
```

Is something like this possible in C? I want to use this to eventually iterate over the whole dna array which is actuality is 60,000 chars long

```
printf("%s.6\n",&dna[1]);
```

printf has this kind of functionality but I want to so this with strcmp. Is there something more efficient than this in C?

Comment: `strncmp(dna + offset, STOP_CODON, 3);`

Comment: Or even: strstr() BTW `char STOP_CODON[3] = "TAA";` will cause the array to be not nul-terminated. Better use `char STOP_CODON[] = "TAA";` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this with `strcmp`, which will compare strings until it sees a null (`'\0'`) character.  Instead, use either [memcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp), which compares a specific number of bytes, or [strncmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp), which allows you to specify the maximum number of characters to compare.

```
// Compare up to 3 characters, stopping at the first null character.
if (strncmp(STOP_CODON, dna, 3) == 0) {
   // they match
}
```

or

```
// Copy exactly 3 bytes, even if they contain null characters.
if (memcmp(STOP_CODON, dna, 3) == 0) {
  // they match
}
```

Note, also, that both of these functions return 0 (not 1) when the strings match.  They'll return a number *less* than zero if the first string is “less than” the second, or a number *greater* than zero if the second string is “less than” the first.

Answer (score 2):

You simply offset into the string, by adding to the pointer.

```
const char* test = "This is a test.";
printf("%s", test+5);   // prints "is a test.";
```

Then you can limit the length of the substring you're checking by using `strncmp`, which take a length parameter.